# Unable to connect to mongodb on remote server

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with a mongo database on localhost and everything work fine.

Now i want to deploy my application to my server and the database is on another remote server.

I changed mongod.conf file and uncommented “bindIp: 0.0.0.0 #default value is 127.0.0.1”

In my application.properties file i have this:

“spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://172.16.4.26:27017/jenkinsdb”

When i run my application i get “com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket” caused by “Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out”

Comment: so you uncommented bindIp ? please read: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/

Comment: i did uncomment that line

Comment: You are building your own MongoDB server, right? If so, what OS you are using, and where it's hosted? In a cloud environment (like AWS, GCP, DO, etc.)? or in a private network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like MongoDB is not accessible over a network there might be several reasons. I have listed some:

- MongoDB port 27017 is not open
- Firewall is blocking the connection with another machine

You can also try adding the authentication information in your URI like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test
```

OR

you can split it over multiple properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongoserver.example.com
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
```

If you want to check whether there is a problem with the application or MongoDB you can spin up the free Mongo Atlas instance and try to connect that with your application if that works then there will be surely a connectivity issue with our machine

Comment: i had to do these commands sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=27017/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload and everything is now working fine